# How to remove last mark strip in join(" | ")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing `tag_links.join(" | ")`

what I does that it add | after each tag. I want to remove | from last one

Comment: Have you tried printing the result?

Comment: Please don't tag the question with irrelevant tags. `join` is a database tag, not a simple join method.

Comment: `join` does not add a separator after each tag. That's the whole point of `join`.

Comment: its add...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get your question right, you want to remove the last `|`.

If it's rails I'd use [#to_sentence](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence)

```
['a', 'b' , 'c'].to_sentence(words_connector: ' | ', last_word_connector: ' ')
=> "a | b c"
```

If it's ruby only:

```
tag_links = ['a', 'b' , 'c']
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
[14] pry(main)> last_tag = tag_links.pop
=> "c"
[15] pry(main)> tag_links.join(' | ') + " " + last_tag
=> "a | b c"
```